# Python keyboard module add_hotkey doesn't work

Tags: python, keyboard, hotkeys

I'm trying to run some code from someone else's GitHub repo, but it wouldn't work. Eventually I figured out that the "keyboard.add_hotkey" function isn't working properly on my PC (W10). I wrote this small test script to isolate the issue:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.write('hehe')
keyboard.add_hotkey('a', lambda: keyboard.write('test'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl + shift + a', print, args =('input', 'hotkey'))
keyboard.hook_key('q', lambda: print(1))

keyboard.wait()
```

The write function works perfectly fine, but all methods of binding a function to a key fails to execute when entering the required input. I ran the exact same code on my laptop (Linux Mint) and it ran perfectly fine. By the way, I also tried "while True: pass" instead of "keyboard.wait()", but that yielded the exact same results on both machines, Linux working fine and W10 not so much.

EDIT:
I tried to run this code on a Linux VM and the code worked perfectly fine, so this must have something to do with my instance of Windows and isn't some weird (physical) keyboard issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Had to turn off one of the starting services (SentryBay) in the boot options. It was conflicting with the keyhooks.